# Start Failed : [FRESH INSTALLATION ANDROID STUDIO]

Tags: android, android-studio

**I was installing Andriod Studio for the first time over my Windows 10. But I encountered this issue!
[ANDRIOD STUDIO VERSION 4.1]**

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1606)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:220)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:550)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:491)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:248)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more

-----
JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre
```

[This is exactly the prompt error which, I receive!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv3Zr.png)

**THE SOLUTIONS I TRIED TO REMOVE THIS ERROR, BUT NONE WORKED ARE LISTED BELOW-**

> **1. Changing these lines of code**
>
> Open the folder where you installed Android Studio:
>
> ex: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin
>
> Find and edit idea.properties. You can edit this with use notepad++ or
> any similar application that allows text editing.
>
> Add this line as the final in the file:
>
> `disable.android.first.run=true`
>
> Now run Android Studio again.

> **2. Opening in Offline Mode**
>
> Close Android Studio Turn off Internet connection and be sure of it.
>
> Start Android Studio. You will see a popup box with Cancel option in it.
>
> Then Click cancel.

> **3. Reinstalling JAVA, PYTHON**
>
> Downloading new package of `ANDRIOD STUDIO` and installing it again after deleting all the previous files

> **4. Adding bin directory to the enviornment variables**
> `JAVA` `PYTHON` `JRE-AndriodStudio`

> **5. Deleting the user plugins that we have in Andriod Studio. [But as its my first time of installation, I am not having them]**

> **6. Even tried restarting my system**

> **7. Closing all other instances running via java, to ensure it not disturbing that particular port number**
>
> But no programmes were running in the process that took the use of java

Answer (score 2):

**Reason:**
If all the 50 ports between 6942 and 6991 are reserved, (e.g.: taken by the other apps then the firewall doesn't allow IDE to bind on them.

**Solution:**
Run the following commands in the Administrator console (cmd.exe):

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=49152 num=16383
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport udp start=49152 num=16383
```

If the above doesn't help, please try these commands instead:

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```